# Groovy: Manipulate variable from within each

Tags: groovy, closures, each

I'd like to manipulate a variable in Groovy from within the closure of each, like this:

```
def stringTest = ''
def foo = ['one', 'two', 'three']
foo.each {
    stringTest.concat(it)
}
println stringTest
```

But this gives me the following error:

> | Error 2013-03-13 15:26:12,330 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR
>   errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NoSuchMethodError occurred when
>   processing request: [GET] /Reporting-Web/reporting/show/1
>   reporting.web.AppFiguresService$_getProductIDs_closure2.(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lgroovy/lang/Reference;)V.
>   Stacktrace follows: Message: Executing action [show] of controller
>   [com.xyz.reporting.ReportingController]  caused exception: Runtime
>   error executing action    Line | Method
>   ->> 195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |    63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter |   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker |
>   918 | run      in     '' ^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
>
> Caused by ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
>   ->> 195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |    63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter |   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker |
>   918 | run      in     '' ^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
>
> Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
>   ->> 195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |    63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter |   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker |
>   918 | run      in     '' ^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
>
> Caused by NoSuchMethodError:
>   reporting.web.Foo$_getProductIDs_closure2.(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lgroovy/lang/Reference;)V
>   ->>  77 | getProductIDs in reporting.web.Foo$$ENzya8Hg
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |    45 | show     in com.xyz.reporting.Foo |   195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter |    63 |
>   doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter |   895 |
>   runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker |   918 |
>   run      in     '' ^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

I'm quite new to Groovy, any help would be great here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
def stringTest = ''
def foo = ['one', 'two', 'three']
foo.each {
    stringTest += it
}
println stringTest
```

Answer (score 1):

the function "concat()" returns a string:

```
stringTest = stringTest.concat(it)
```

To modify the iterator in the closure is not possible.

//Edit
The error msg is a grails error, while the controller can not open the function "show()"

Comment: Thx, but this gives the same error, even if I change the line to this: stringTest.concat('test')

Comment: The error msg is thrown by the controller. It can't open the method show(Long id)

Comment: Yep. Later, I'll break this down to a pure Groovy example and try to reproduce it without any full blown framework surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

Java strings are immutable. You can collect the concatened string:

```
def stringTest = ''
def foo = ['one', 'two', 'three']
stringTest = foo.collect { stringTest + it }.join()

assert stringTest == "onetwothree"
```

Comment: it's not a string, it's a gstring.